# Why won't my merged images appear (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

In my `index.js` file, I'm trying to merge two images together with my `pv()` function.  Whenever I hit `cmd + s` -> `cmd + r` to reload the page, it's just completely blank.  In other words, my code is messed up.  How do I make my merged images appear?

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>My practice web app</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var Website = React.createClass({

   scrolling: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".scrollToPortfolio").offset().top
        },'slow');
   },

   scrollToAbout: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".scrollToAbout").offset().top
     },'slow');
   },

   scrollToContact: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".scrollToContact").offset().top
     },'slow')
   },

   pv: function() {
     var c = document.getElementsByClassName('pv');
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
     var catering1 = new Image();
     var contact1 = new Image();

     catering1.src = "./catering1.png";
     catering1.onload = function() {
       ctx.drawImage(catering1,0,0,328,526);
       contact1.src = "./contact1.png";
       contact1.onload = function() {
         ctx.drawImage(contact1,0,0,328,526);
       }
     }
   },



  render: function() {
    return(

      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">My practice web app</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.scrolling} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToAbout} type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToContact}type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>

        <div className="trainPic">
        <img src={"./pictures/myPic3.JPG"} className="myPic"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToPortfolio">
          <h1><u>Portfolio</u></h1>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail pv"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToAbout">
          <h1><u>About</u></h1>
          <h2>Text</h2>
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToContact">
          <h1><u>Contact</u></h1>
          <h2>Contact info and what not</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Here are the `errors` I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (39:2)
at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2027)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:2596)
at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:2590)
at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:1447)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:1250)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:26392)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:1097)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:1079)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:1035)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:1018)
http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server             responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I believe you are just missing a comma `,` at the end of your `pw` function

Comment: @wilburrr90 ok I did that, my page isn't blank anymore.  but I don't see my merged images.

Answer (score 0):

[`getContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) function should be applied to the canvas element.

`<canvas className="img-responsive img-thumbnail pv"></canvas>`

And we need to apply this function to the single element:

`document.getElementsByClassName('pv')[0]`

Comment: I tried your edit, my page is not blank anymore, but I don't see the merged images.  Maybe my `pv()` function is a little off?

Comment: Where your `pv()` function is fired? I'll suggest to place the code inside this function into `componentDidMount()` function

Comment: What are you talking about?  I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Add new function: `componentDidMount: function() { /* var c = document.getElementsByClassName('pv')[0]; .... */ }`. I also recommend to read about [component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)